# Prove that $ \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n > \frac{1}{6} $ for $n\geq 2$

Tags: real-analysis, induction

Prove that $ \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n > \frac{1}{6} $ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $ n\ge 2$

Indeed, the affirmation is true even if $n$ is not a natural ($ n\geq 2 $ ) and we can prove it using calculus. But, this is part of a question about limit of sequences (that is why I fixed $n$ a natural number), so I can't officially use derivative yet. Then, I was thinking to use induction.

For $n = 2$ it is clearly true. If we have $ (1 - \frac{1}{n})^n > \frac{1}{6}$ , then for $n>1$ 
$$ \left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} > \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1} > \frac{1}{6} \left(1-\frac{1}{n} \right) .$$ But it is not helping.

I would appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, I thought $(1-{1\over n})^n\to e^{-1}$...

Comment: @abiessu I already edited it, sorry. This is what I have to prove.

Comment: Can you use Bernoulli's inequality?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, but I'm not seeing how this can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove by induction that

$$\left(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} > \left(1 - \frac1n\right)^n.$$

Bring that into the form

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2-1}\right)^n > 1 + \frac1n,$$

which is seen to be true by Bernoulli's inequality.

Comment: @DanielFisher If I prove that $(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1} > (1-\frac{1}{n})^{n} $ it follows, again by induction, that $(1 - \frac{1}{n} ) > 1/6 $. I will try to work in your proposition, thanks

Comment: I suppose you mean "prove _for_ induction" (_by_ Bernoulli's inequality).

Answer (score 1):

If we are to show the given statement is true for all $n$, it suffices to show it is true for $n=2$ (trivially, $\tfrac 14\gt \tfrac 16$), and then show that for all $n, a_{n+1}\gt a_n$.

In order to show that $a_{n+1}\gt a_n$, one option is to apply the ratio test:

$${\left(1-{1\over n+1}\right)^{n+1}\over \left(1-{1\over n}\right)^n}\gt 1$$

Reduce this inequality to finish the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Bernoulli's Inequality says that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n}
&=\frac{n}{n+1}\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^{-n}\tag{1a}\\
&\ge\frac{n}{n+1}\left(1+\frac1n\right)\tag{1b}\\[9pt]
&=1\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
That is, $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n$ is increasing in $n$.

For $n=2$, $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n=\frac14$. Thus, for $n\ge2$, we have
$$
\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\ge\frac14\tag2
$$