# Bounds on factorial with powers of two

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, factorial, upper-lower-bounds

Consider the following calculation:

$$16!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10\cdot11\cdot12\cdot13\cdot14\cdot15\cdot16$$
$$\phantom{16!}\leq1\cdot2\cdot4\cdot4\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8\!\cdot\!16\!\cdot16\cdot16\cdot16\cdot16\cdot16\cdot16\cdot16$$
$$=2^1\cdot4^2\cdot8^4\cdot16^8$$
$$=(2^1)^{2^0}\cdot(2^2)^{2^1}\cdot(2^3)^{2^2}\cdot(2^4)^{2^3}$$
$$=2^{(1\cdot2^0+2\cdot2^1+3\cdot2^2+4\cdot2^3)}$$
$$=2^{49}$$

In general, the factorial of a power of two is bounded by

$$(2^n)!\leq2^{(1\cdot2^0+2\cdot2^1+\cdots+n\cdot2^{n-1})}.$$

Here we'll use the identity $1+2x+3x^2+\cdots+nx^{n-1}=(1-(n+1)x^n+nx^{n+1})/(1-x)^2$, which can be gotten by differentiating $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n=(1-x^{n+1})/(1-x)$, thus:

$$(2^n)!\leq2^{(1-(n+1)2^n+n2^{n+1})}$$
$$=2^{(1+(n-1)2^n)}$$
$$=2\cdot\left(\frac{2^n}{2}\right)^{2^n}$$

---

Now consider the "opposite" calculation:

$$15!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10\cdot11\cdot12\cdot13\cdot14\cdot15$$
$$\phantom{16!}\geq1\cdot2\cdot2\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot8\cdot8\cdot\,8\;\cdot\;8\;\cdot\;8\;\cdot\;8\;\cdot\;8\;\cdot\;8$$
$$=1^1\cdot2^2\cdot4^4\cdot8^8$$
$$=(2^0)^{2^0}\cdot(2^1)^{2^1}\cdot(2^2)^{2^2}\cdot(2^3)^{2^3}$$
$$=2^{(0\cdot2^0+1\cdot2^1+2\cdot2^2+3\cdot2^3)}$$
$$=2^{34}$$

In general we have

$$(2^n-1)!\geq2^{(1\cdot2^1+2\cdot2^2+\cdots+(n-1)\cdot2^{n-1})},$$

which simplifies thus:

$$=2^{2(1\cdot2^0+2\cdot2^1+\cdots+(n-1)\cdot2^{n-2})}$$
$$=2^{2(1-n2^{n-1}+(n-1)2^n)}$$
$$=2^{(2+(n-2)2^n)}$$
$$=4\cdot\left(\frac{2^n}{4}\right)^{2^n}$$

---

These two results suggest the inequality

> $$4\cdot\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^n\quad\leq\quad(n-1)!\quad\leq\quad n!\quad\leq\quad2\cdot\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n$$

We've shown that it's true when $n$ is a power of two. Is it true for all $n$?

Comment: Partial duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2005324/472818

Answer (score 4):

For the upper bound, we can use the AM-GM inequality. First we consider the case where $n=2m$ is even:

$$n!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots(m-1)\cdot m\cdot(m+1)\cdots(2m-2)\cdot(2m-1)\cdot(2m)$$
$$=1(2m-1)\cdot2(2m-2)\cdot3(2m-3)\cdots(m-1)(m+1)\cdot m\cdot(2m)$$
$$\leq\quad(m)^2\quad\cdot\quad(m)^2\quad\cdot\quad(m)^2\quad\cdots\quad(m)^2\quad\cdot\quad m\cdot(2m)$$
$$=(m^2)^{m-1}\cdot m\cdot(2m)$$
$$=2\cdot m^{2m}$$
$$=2\cdot\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n$$

Next we consider the case where $n=2m+1$ is odd:

$$n!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots(m-1)\cdot m\cdot(m+1)\cdots(2m-1)\cdot(2m)\cdot(2m+1)$$
$$=1(2m)\cdot2(2m-1)\cdot3(2m-2)\cdots m(m+1)\cdot(2m+1)$$
$$\leq\;(m+\tfrac12)^2\;\cdot\;(m+\tfrac12)^2\;\cdot\;(m+\tfrac12)^2\;\cdots\;(m+\tfrac12)^2\;\cdot\;(2m+1)$$
$$=\big((m+\tfrac12)^2\big)^m\cdot(2m+1)$$
$$=2\cdot(m+\tfrac12)^{2m+1}$$
$$=2\cdot\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n$$

For the lower bound, we can use induction. Suppose the bound is valid, $(n-1)!\geq4(n/4)^n$, for some number $n$. Then for the next number we have

$$n!=n\cdot(n-1)!$$
$$\geq n\cdot4\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^n$$
$$=4\cdot\frac{n^{n+1}}{4^n}$$
$$\overset?\geq4\cdot\left(\frac{n+1}{4}\right)^{n+1}$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{4^n}$$

so the result will be established if we can get that questioned inequality:

$$4\cdot n^{n+1}\overset?\geq(n+1)^{n+1}$$
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\overset?\geq\frac{1}{4}$$

This is seen to be true, e.g. here: [Prove that $ \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n > \frac{1}{6} $ for $n\geq 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/515637/472818)

Comment: In fact we can use induction for the upper bound as well, since $(1+1/n)^n\geq2$.